# How to show and hide a paragraph in html when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, css, html, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have the following query. I have a `<pre>` tag and it has some text inside but i want to hide `<pre>` when a button is clicked. Following images shows code:

[image]

When this `addNewTest()` function is called on click, I want `<pre>` to be hidden. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add an id:

```
<pre id="myId" ....
```

And then hide it with jquery:

```
addNewTest = function() {
    $('#myId').hide();
});
```

or without jquery:

```
addNewTest = function() {
    document.getElementById('myId').style.display = 'none';
});
```